# extjs 4 how to reverse the output from json?

Tags: extjs, couchdb, extjs4

i'm working with couchdb as database.. i need show the data in pagination grid..
i can handle the `next page` proccess... but i am stack in how to handle `previous page`

after hard trying,... i can show previous json like this :

`http://localhost/myapp/_view/getAll?limit=2&startkey=10&skip=1&descending=true`
and the response :

```
{
    total_rows: 21,
    offset: 12,
    rows: [{
        id: "fd899e87f9f682a4df71d9e2a9010b26",
        key: 9,
        value: {
            _id: "fd899e87f9f682a4df71d9e2a9010b26",
            _rev: "1-ce4ed0e621ae53996f323a8927bcf470",
            $type: "siswa",
            Nama: "test9",
            Agama: "Islam",
            Hobi: ["Membaca","Menulis"]
        }
    } , {
        id: "fd899e87f9f682a4df71d9e2a9010622",
        key: 8,
        value: {
            _id: "fd899e87f9f682a4df71d9e2a9010622",
            _rev: "1-45c71654623d385bd95f6970c72dce50",
            $type: "siswa",
            Nama: "test8",
            Agama: "Islam",
            Hobi: ["Membaca","Menulis"]
        }
    }]
}
```

the shown data is in reverse format.
as you can see, the response json start with key 9, and then 8..
so, the solution is reverse back in extjs / UI..

how to reverse data from store in extjs 4 ?
in ext 3 i do that like this : `this.store.reader.reversed = true;` and then reload the store..

Comment: why not to use db `order by`?

Comment: and may by [this]http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store will help you

Comment: afaik,.. there is no order by in couchdb (view) http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API ...

i'm using NoSQL database.. it means no query

Comment: and i think it should be in the json reader, not in store it self

Comment: set store's sorters: [{property : 'key',direction: 'ASC'}]

Comment: or u had to override Reader#extractData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort you store like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        sorters: [
        {
            property : 'key',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }
        // ...
}
```

or call `store.sort('key', 'ASC');`

Comment: thanks for your reply... but it's still not working,... i guess mybe this is a bug..

Comment: Did you set [root](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-root): 'rows' in the json reader?

Comment: ah,... sorry... this my bad,... the problem is not the sorters,... but `remoteSort` and the server side. the url keep append the sort variable. even when i set remoteSort to false (manually).. but thanks... i'll mark your answer, because exactly this is how to sort..